# Shutdown Tomcat instance using Java

Tags: java, tomcat

I am running an application using tomcat as the container - at start up, several files need to be found and loaded. However, if one of these files doesn't exist or can't be read, I want to log the exception and exit the app, which I am currently doing using System.exit(1)... however, is there a better way of doing this?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: An easy solution would be to modify the Tomcat's startup script to check for files...

Comment: If these files are specific to the application, then I don't think its really advised to manipulate tomcat's startup scripts?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know if this fits your needs but it actually worked for my app. The listener is 
called at application start, if it is declared in your web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>your.package.TestServletListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

There you can do testing and call the ShutdownThread if one fails. It will connect to Tomcats shutdown port and send the shutdown command as a String:

```
public class TestServletListener implements ServletContextListener {

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Starting app, running 5 tests ...");

    // do tests ...
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("testing ... " + i);
        waitFor(1000);
    }
    // If a test failed call:
    System.out.println("test failed!");
    new ShutdownTask().start();
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    System.out.print("Stopping app, cleaning up (takes 3 sec) ... ");
    waitFor(3000);
    System.out.println("done");
}

private void waitFor(int i) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(i);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ShutdownTask extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8015);
            PrintStream os = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
            os.println("shutdown");
            s.close();
            System.out.println("Shutting down server ...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

You need to make sure that the shutdown port and shutdown command are in sync with your Tomcats server.xml:

```
...
<Server port="8015" shutdown="shutdown">
...
```

For example, you could pass them as context parameters in your web.xml. Like System.exit(...) this is not going to work (without further config) if Tomcat is running with a SecurityManager.

Comment: Yes, that seems like something I could use - didn't know the listener could be used like that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should consider **embedding Tomcat**, i.e. have your `AppStarter` class perform those checks and then start Tomcat:

```
public class AppStarter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Check if everything is ready...
        if (file1.exists() && file2.exists() && condition3) {
            // Start Tomcat here.
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid configuration.");
        }
    }
}
```

You can find how to embed Tomcat tutorials on the Internet.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't embed tomcat in the application.. I'm guessing that System.exit() is probably the only way to do it (besides calling kill -15 on the app from a System call)

Comment: You can throw an exception in you servlet's constructor thus preventing the application starting, but Tomcat will still be running. Other than `System.exit()` I don't see any other way.

Comment: I stop tomcat with `catalina stop` on command line. Wouldn't it help if paths are set correctly?

Comment: @Piro I don't understand the question.

Comment: From command line i can write `catalina start` or `catalina stop` to start/stop Tomcat. But path must be set to tomcat binaries where catalina script/program is

Comment: You need to add `${tomcat}\bin` folder to PATH environment variable (and restart console/terminal window). You could use `startup` and `shutdown` instead of `catalina xxxx`.